# React - how to navigate from "/" route properly based on user role

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an app where I have 2 user roles (User, Admin). Let's say that user is already logged in.

When the user enters in url for example "localhost:3000", basically he is on the "/" route and there I don't have any content, just routes, and I want to navigate from "/" based on his user role. If he is User, navigate to "localhost:3000/user", if Admin, navigate to "localhost:3000/admin".

I tried with code below with *navigateUser()* but I don't know if thats the best solution. Can someone help me with this?

App.js

```
function App() {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

  const navigateUser = () => {
    if (!authCtx.isLoggedIn) {
      return;
    }

    if (authCtx.user.role === 'user') {
      return <Navigate replace to="/user" />;
    } else {
      return <Navigate replace to="/admin" />;
    }
  };

  const userRoutes = (
    <Route element={<RoleGuard role={'user'} />}>
      <Route path="/user" element={<User/>} />
    </Route>
  );

  const adminRoutes = (
    <Route element={<RoleGuard role={'admin'} />}>
      <Route path="/admin" element={<p>ADMIN</p>} />
    </Route>
  );

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" exact element={navigateUser()} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

      <Route element={<PrivateRoute token={authCtx.isLoggedIn} />}>
        {userRoutes}

        {adminRoutes}
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: From what I can understand of the code and if this code is working for you, then I don't see much room for improvement/optimization here. Maybe a tiny effort to make it a bit more **DRY**, but that's about it.